# URLs appearing twice in Google Search

Tags: google-search, url

While checking using `site:example.com` in Google, certain URLs are seen twice. The URLs are exactly the same.

Can anyone explain why so?

Comment: Can you please paste the URL ?

Comment: canonicalization issue?